# ServiceStack + Swagger-UI How can I show if a property is required or optional?

Tags: servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I display the optional/required info on the Model as highlight in yellow?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to convey required/optional DTO properties in ServiceStack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685296/whats-the-best-way-to-convey-required-optional-dto-properties-in-servicestack)

Comment: So you just need to use the attribute `[ApiMember(IsRequired = false)]`

Answer (score -2):

```
"definitions":{
"RequestLogs":{
**"required":["BeforeSecs","AfterSecs"]**
"properties":{
"BeforeSecs":{
"type":"integer"
},
"AfterSecs":{
"type":"integer"
},
"IpAddress":{
"type""string"
}
}

}
}
```